# How to insert a text into Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, text, coordinates, worksheet

Purpose is using C# to insert one image and accompanying text into Excel file with the coordinates of the picture. The inserting image is OK, but I cannot do like that for any text.

For example : Image's coordinate : top = 14f, left = 16f

My code  for inserting image:

```
Excel.Shape img = worksheet.Shapes(,,top,left,width,height);
```

My code  for inserting text:

```
worksheet.Cells[x,y] = "jdshfg";
```

This is the Text insertion function for one cell using row and column in Excel.

I want to get [x,y] from top, left (image's coordinates) for this cell.

Comment: sorry: worksheet.Cells[x,y] = "jdshfg"; for inserting Text, not Image

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want convert from an Excel-style row/column coordinate to pixel coordinates. I've ran into the same issue when inserting charts. The first function below will give you your 'x', the second your 'y'.

```
public double CellRangeToPixelWidth(Worksheet sheet, int left, int right) {
  Range range = sheet.get_Range(CellString(left - 1, 1, right - 1, 1), Type.Missing);
  return range.Width;
}

public double CellRangeToPixelHeight(Worksheet sheet, int top, int bottom) {
  Range range = sheet.get_Range(CellString(0, top, 0, bottom), Type.Missing);
  return range.Height;
}

public string CellString(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  return string.Format("{0}{1}:{2}{3}", CellString(left), top, CellString(right), bottom);
}

public string CellString(int col) {
  if (col < 26)
    return ((char)('A' + col)).ToString();
  else if (col < 27 * 26)
    return ((char)('A' + col / 26 - 1)).ToString() + ((char)('A' + col % 26)).ToString();
  return "";
}
```